# Sum of orthogonal complements of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V_1$ and $V_2$ are subspaces of vector space $V$, where $V$ is a finite-dimensional inner product space then:

$(V_1+V_2)^⊥=V_1^⊥+V_2^⊥$

So far I have tried showing this, by taking a vector $u \in  V_1^⊥+V_2^⊥ $

Then $u=k+w $  with $k\in  V_1^⊥$ and $ w \in V_2^⊥$, so if I take a vector
$v \in V_1+V_2 $ then I have to show that $ <u,v>=0$.
I can also write $v=a+b$ with $a\in V_1$ and $b\in V_2$ but at this point I'm stuck.

Comment: This is false, take $V_1$ a strict subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $V_2=(0)$...

Comment: @Dark Why does it need to be a strict subspace?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 sorry I meant $V_1$ a non trivial subspace.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is not true. For example, take $V=\Bbb{R}^2$, $V_1=\langle(1,0)^t\rangle$, and $V_2=\langle(0,1)^t\rangle$. Now, we have $V_1^\bot=\langle(0,1)^t\rangle$ and $V_2^\bot=\langle(1,0)^t,(0,1)^t\rangle$, so:

$$V_1^\bot+V_2^\bot=\langle(0,1)^t,(1,0)^t\rangle=\Bbb{R}^2$$

However, $V_1+V_2=\langle(1,0)^t,(0,1)^t\rangle$, meaning:
$$(V_1+V_2)^\bot=\langle(0,0)^t\rangle$$

Now, according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744511/orthogonal-complement-of-a-sum), we actually have the following:
$$(V_1+V_2)^\bot=V_1^\bot \cap V_2^\bot$$
$$(V_1 \cap V_2)^\bot=V_1^\bot + V_2^\bot$$

Comment: Even in 2 dimensions. In $R^2$, when $V_1$ is the x-axis and $V_2$ is the y-axis, the statement is not true.

Comment: @user254665 Good point. I've fixed the answer to have your examplle.

Comment: Your original A was fine.  But 2-d is simpler.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet in $\mathbb R^2$, can't we just take the entire space and the zero space?

Comment: @CuriousKid7. Good one.Yes.