# The set of all vectors $B\in\Bbb{R}^n$ such that $B$ is perpendicular to both $A_1,A_2$ is a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Lang's: Linear Algebra. There is an exercise:

> Let $A_1, A_2$ be vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$. Show that the set of all vectors $B\in\Bbb{R}^n$ such that $B$ is perpendicular to both $A_1,A_2$ is a subspace.

I did the following: Using the inner product given before:

- $$\langle B,A_n \rangle\stackrel{!}{=}0 $$
- $$\langle \alpha B,A_n \rangle\stackrel{?}{=}0 \\ \alpha  \langle B,A_n \rangle\stackrel{?}{=}0 \\  \alpha  0\stackrel{!}{=}0$$
- $$\langle \alpha B+\beta B,A_n \rangle\stackrel{?}{=}0 \\ \  \langle (\alpha +\beta )B,A_n \rangle\stackrel{?}{=}0 \\  (\alpha +\beta )  \langle B,A_n \rangle\stackrel{?}{=}0\\  (\alpha +\beta )  0\stackrel{!}{=}0$$

I'm not sure if that is correct though. As we're talking about $\Bbb{R}^n$ there could be more than one vector perpendicular to those two, but the only one I have guarantee that is perpendicular is $B$, given by the exercise.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding in place. You showed that the set is closed under multiplication by scalar, but the second one seems confused. You should show that given $B_1$ and $B_2$ in the set, then their sum is also in the set (which is a straightforward computation). Just switch $\alpha B$ to $B_1$ and $\beta B$ to $B_2$.

Comment: Let $V_1$ -set of vectors perepedincular to $A_1$ and $V_2$ -set of vectors perepedincular to $A_2$. We know that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are subspaces,
hence $V_1 \cap V_2$ is also subspace and this is the desired set.

Comment: You need to check $\langle\alpha B_1+\beta B_2,A_n\rangle$=0.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way:

You want to show that $B=($ span$(A_1\cup A_2))^\perp =(A_1+ A_2)^\perp=(A_1)^\perp+ (A_2)^\perp$

where the last equality is shown here: 
[orthogonal complement of a sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744511/orthogonal-complement-of-a-sum)

Then you would have:

$(A_1)^\perp+ (A_2)^\perp=$span$((A_1)^\perp\cup(A_2)^\perp)$ 
but a span is a vector subspace, therefore, $B$ is a vector subspace.